# Prove an estimate in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem from Gamelin's complex analysis book that I am tring to solve.

Suppose D is a bounded domain with piecewise smooth boundary, and that $f(z)$ is analytic on $D \cup \partial{D} $. Show that:

$$
\sup|\bar{z} -f(z)| \geq 2 \frac{\operatorname{Area}(D)}{\operatorname{Length}(\partial D)}
$$

Show that this estimate is sharp, and that in fact there exist $D$ and $f(z)$ for which the equality holds.

I have tried to work out this problem but still didn't make much progress.

Comment: Hint: Length * sup suggests M-L estimate.  Think about $\int_{\partial D}(\bar{z}-f(z))\,\mathrm{d}z$.

Comment: Could you give me more hints? Thank you.

Comment: Expanding on what @user10354138 said:$\frac12\oint_{\partial D} \overline{z}dz=\text{Area}(D)$ is Green's theorem. What is $\oint_{\partial D}f(z)$?